# React and TypeScript—which types for an Axios response?

Tags: reactjs, typescript, axios

I am trying to present a simple user list from an API which returns this:

```
[{"UserID":2,"FirstName":"User2"},{"UserID":1,"FirstName":"User1"}]
```

I do not understand fully how to handle Axios responses with types. The TypeScript error is

> Type '{} | { id: number; firstName: string; }' is not assignable to type 'IntrinsicAttributes & UserListProps & { children?: ReactNode; }'.
>
> Property 'items' is missing in type '{}' but required in type 'UserListProps'.

from the `<UserList />` element in the `Users.tsx` file below. Is my `User` interface wrong?

```
import React, {useEffect, useState, Fragment } from 'react';
import UserList from './UserList';
import axios, {AxiosResponse} from 'axios';

interface User {
    id: number;
    firstName: string;
}

const Users: React.FC = (props) => {
    const [users, setUserList] = useState<User>();

    useEffect(() => {
        // Use [] as second argument in useEffect for not rendering each time
        axios.get('http://localhost:8080/admin/users')
        .then((response: AxiosResponse) => {
            console.log(response.data);
            setUserList( response.data );
        });
    }, []);

    return (
        <Fragment>
            <UserList {...users} />
        </Fragment>

    );
};
export default Users;
```

Below is my `UserList.tsx`.

```
import React, {Fragment } from 'react';

interface UserListProps {
    items: {id: number, firstName: string}[];
};

const UserList: React.FC<UserListProps> = (props) => {
    return (
        <Fragment>
            <ul>
            {props.items.map(user => (
                <li key={user.id}>
                    <span>{user.firstName}</span>
                    {/* not call delete function, just point to it
                    // set this to null in bind() */}
                </li>
            ))}
            </ul>
        </Fragment>
    );
};

export default UserList;
```

Answer (score 125, accepted):

There is [generic `get` method defined in **axios/index.d.ts**](https://github.com/axios/axios/blob/7d6bddba2d8de29c263feaef4c40daa50cb4b176/index.d.ts#L146)

```js
get<T = never, R = AxiosResponse<T>>(url: string, config?: AxiosRequestConfig<T>): Promise<R>;
```

*Example*

```js
interface User {
    id: number;
    firstName: string;
}


axios.get<User[]>('http://localhost:8080/admin/users')
        .then(response => {
            console.log(response.data);
            setUserList( response.data );
        });
```

I think you are passing list the wrong way to child component.

```js
const [users, setUserList] = useState<User[]>([]);
```

```
<UserList items={users} />
```

```js
interface UserListProps {
    items: User[];
};
```

```js
const UserList: React.FC<UserListProps> = ({items}) => {
    return (
        <Fragment>
            <ul>
            {items.map(user => (
                <li key={user.id}>
                    <span>{user.firstName}</span>
                </li>
            ))}
            </ul>
        </Fragment>
    );
};
```

Comment: thanks, so I should use `axios.get<User>` instead of `useState<User>()`? If I try that, Typescript complains about `useState()` being undefined.

Comment: Updated answer. I thought at first you are just getting single object but this is actually an array. Just put `[]` brackets in few places

Comment: I think the only missing part now is how i initialize `useState()`. I get this: `Argument of type 'User[]' is not assignable to parameter of type 'SetStateAction<undefined>'.
  Type 'User[]' provides no match for the signature '(prevState: undefined): undefined'.ts(2345)`

Comment: You have to initialize `useState([])` with empty array. Otherwise you have to extend type `useState<User[] | undefined>()` add checking if variable is undefined in child component and do something about it

Comment: What about when using responseType: 'stream' ?

Answer (score 13):

You need to provide a type argument when calling `axios.get` if you do not want Axios to infer the type for the value `response` as any.

And you are passing an incorrect type argument when you `useState` to create the array of users.

#### The correct way

```js
interface User {
  id: number;
  firstName: string;
}

// Initialized as an empty array
const [users, setUserList] = useState<User[]>([]); // 'users' will be an array of users
```

For example,

```js
import React, {useEffect, useState, Fragment } from 'react';
import UserList from './UserList';
import axios from 'axios';

interface User {
  id: number;
  firstName: string;
}

// You can export the type TUserList to use as -
// props type in your `UserList` component
export type TUserList = User[]

const Users: React.FC = (props) => {
   // You can also use User[] as a type argument
    const [users, setUserList] = useState<TUserList>();

    useEffect(() => {
        // Use [] as a second argument in useEffect for not rendering each time
        axios.get<TUserList>('http://localhost:8080/admin/users')
        .then((response) => {
            console.log(response.data);
            setUserList(response.data);
        });
    }, []);

    return (
        <Fragment>
            <UserList {...users} />
        </Fragment>

    );
};
export default Users;
```

If you choose to export the type `type TUserList = User[]`, you can use it in your `UserList` component as the type for props. For example,

```
import React, {Fragment } from 'react';
import { TUserList } from './Users';

interface UserListProps {
    items: TUserList // Don't have to redeclare the object again
};

const UserList: React.FC<UserListProps> = (props) => {
    return (
        <Fragment>
            <ul>
            {props.items.map(user => (
                <li key={user.id}>
                    <span>{user.firstName}</span>
                    { /* Do not call the delete function. Just point
                         to it. Set this to null in bind(). */}
                </li>
            ))}
            </ul>
        </Fragment>
    );
};

export default UserList;
```

Comment: very good point about exporting the `TUserList` type, thank you very much for an excellent answer :)