# Typescript: React Child Component Types

Tags: reactjs, typescript

I'm refactoring my React app to Typescript. I added types for the child component, but now that I'm working on the Parent component, I'm lost as to how to type this.

I fetch data from an endpoint and pass it down to `Recommendations` along with the boolean value of `loading`. How do I add types for the Parent here and what do I need to change when passing here: `<Recommendations title={"Trending"} data={trending} loading={isLoading} />`?

Also, my app compiles correctly, but did I do this correctly in child component?

### App Component (Parent)

```js
const App = (): ReactElement => {
  const [trending, setTrending] = useState([]);
  const [isLoading, setIsLoading] = useState<boolean>(false);

  useEffect(() => {
    const fetchTrending = async () => {
      setIsLoading(true);

      const res = await fetch(
        `https://api.themoviedb.org/3/trending/movie/day?api_key=${API_KEY}`
      );
      const data = await res.json();
      const results = data.results;

      setTrending(results);
      setIsLoading(false);
    };

    fetchTrending();
  }, [API_KEY]);

  return (
    <div className="App">
      <Recommendations title={"Trending"} data={trending} loading={isLoading} />
    </div>
  );
};

export default App;
```

### Recommendations Component (Child)

```js
interface IRecommendationData {
  data: Array<IRecommendations>;
  loading: boolean;
  title: string;
}

interface IRecommendations {
  title: string;
  id: string;
  poster_path: string;
}

const Recommendations = ({title, data, loading}: IRecommendationData): ReactElement => {
  
  return (
    <div className="recommendationSection">
      <h3>{title}</h3>

      {loading ? (
        <h3>Loading...</h3>
      ) : (
        <Slider {...settings}>
          {data.map((movie) => {
            return (
              <Link
                to={{
                  pathname: `/movie/${movie.id}`,
                  state: { ...movie },
                }}
                key={movie.title}
              >
                <div className="banner recBanner">
                  <img
                    src={
                      movie.poster_path
                        ? `https://image.tmdb.org/t/p/original/${movie.poster_path}`
                        : "https://www.genius100visions.com/wp-content/uploads/2017/09/placeholder-vertical.jpg"
                    }
                    alt={movie.title}
                  />
                </div>
              </Link>
            );
          })}
        </Slider>
      )}
    </div>
  );
};

export default Recommendations;
```

## --- EDIT ---

### App Component (Parent)

#### In the parent I took that second `interface` from the child and then exported it, [as per this post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/62217859/9370085), as an array of `interface`s.

```js
interface IRecommendations {
  title: string;
  id: string;
  poster_path: string;
}

export type RecommendationData = IRecommendations[];

const [trending, setTrending] = useState<IRecommendations[]>([]);
```

### Recommendations Component (Child)

#### Then I set the `data` to said imported `interface` and set the props type to that.

```js
import { RecommendationData } from "../../pages/Home";

interface IRecommendationData {
  data: RecommendationData;
  loading: boolean;
  title: string;
}

const Recommendations = ({title, data, loading}: RecommendationData): ReactElement => {
```

Comment: your code seems pretty good. Only thing is, since `data` is of type `Array<IRecommendations>`, you should type the `useState` hook that way too: `const [trending, setTrending] = useState<Array<IRecommendations>>([])`

Comment: thanks @BaoHuynhLam, but the types are declared in the child component. Do I move one/both of them up to the parent and somehow pass them down? I can't just write `const [trending, setTrending] = useState<Array<IRecommendations>>([])` because that's in the parent and I currently have no types set there. That's where I'm confused. I did things backwards by adding types to the child first and now I'm trying to figure out how to do this correctly.

Comment: The data is fetched in the parent, so parent should be the one that knows and controls the data interfaces. Move the interface declarations to the parent file, and export them so the child file could import and use.

Comment: hey @BaoHuynhLam, yeah i just edited my post with some changes. can you let me know how this looks? i think thats what i did from my research.

Comment: Looks good but there is a typo. The props type for child component should be `IRecommendationData`, not `RecommendationData`:  `const Recommendations = ({title, data, loading}: IRecommendationData): ReactElement =>`. I usually opt for a interface naming schemes like this: Props interface = Component name + "Props" (i.e `RecommendationsProps` instead of `IRecommendationData`), and I would remove the "I" from interface names - `SingleRecommendation` instead of `IRecommendations`. So yeah, beware of your own naming schemes to not get things mixed up

Comment: thanks @BaoHuynhLam! Yeah, I just made a typo here in SO. I had in correct in my app, but you're right about the naming convention. That makes more sense. In my learnings, I saw a lot of folks opt for "I"+name for it so I just followed suit. I just want to know what 2021's "best practices" are and follow them but its hard with so much info out there from different years.

Comment: Not really best practices, just personal preference. You may like to use "I" and it's fine. "I" or not, if the main content/main name remains descriptive, it is still good. Just create a convention of your own and stick with it. By the way, if you have solved the question, consider writing an answer for others with similar problem can see