# How can I set the types for a destructured value

Tags: typescript, axios

I have an axios POST like this:

```
axios
      .post(url, payload)
      .then((res) => {
        // eslint-disable-next-line @typescript-eslint/no-unsafe-assignment
        const { someObject } = res.data;
        // eslint-disable-next-line @typescript-eslint/no-unsafe-assignment
        const { someString } = res.data;
...
```

Currently I have to disable the eslint for those lines. How can I avoid this?

I did try creating interfaces and getting `res` and `res.data` `as AxiosResponse`, but no luck

Comment: Try `generic` See [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62217642/react-and-typescript-which-types-for-axios-response)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let's define the request response type. `axios.post` is a generic function, then you can define the response of the post request:

```
interface IPostResponse {
  someObject: { name: string };
  otherField: number;
}

axios.post<IPostResponse>(url, payload)
  .then(res => {
    // res.data is a IPostResponse
    const { someObject } = res.data; // someObject is a { name: string }
  })
```

Answer (score 0):

Generally, you can annotate the type for a desctructered object like so:

`const { someString }: {someString: someType} = res.data;`

where someType is the appropriate type

Comment: Yeah, good suggestion but the linting rules on this project didn't like that either